# Fate Reforged Booster Pack contains a Khans of Tarkir Fetch Land

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I'm kind of new to Magic.  Today I opened a Fate Reforge booster pack that instead of containing a basic landed contained a [Windswept Heath](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Windswept%20Heath).  That is a fetch land from Khans.  Is it normal for the Fate Reforge boosters to contain Khans cards?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, Fate Reforged packs may contain KTK Fetchlands.

More information at: http://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/feature/fetching-look-fate-reforged-2014-12-24

Comment: Also worth mentioning here that all Fate Reforged packs contain one of the two dual land types from Khans. It's just that usually the land card is the lifegain dual that comes into play tapped, not the fetchland.